# SQL Server trigger to update one value in a table after insert into another table if criteria are met

Tags: sql-server, triggers, multiple-tables

**Update: Just to eliminate one possible suggestion, I saved the first query as a view and substituted it in the trigger. No change in behavior has been observed. I have updated the code below to reflect the new arrangement.**

I have just started working with SQL Server triggers and have had some success. The current bit that I'm working on has me confused.

I am working with two tables. One is an order header and the other contains the line items. The trigger is watching for a new row to be inserted in the line item table and, if the item added meets certain criteria, update a value in the order header table. When I break my query down and run it separately, I get what I expect. A list of orders that contain the items I am watching for.

```
--QUERY WORKS AS EXPECTED
SELECT ord_no, cmt_cd_1 
FROM OrderHeader
WHERE ord_no IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT OrderHeader.ord_no
    FROM OrderLine INNER JOIN OrderHeader 
    ON OrderLine.ord_no = OrderHeader.ord_no
    WHERE (OrderLine.item_no LIKE 'A%') OR
          (OrderLine.item_no LIKE 'B%') OR
          (OrderLine.item_no LIKE 'C30%'))
```

However, when I try to use this in a trigger, it doesn't work.

```
--TRIGGER DOES NOT UPDATE ANY RECORDS
CREATE TRIGGER add_cmt_cd
ON [OrderLine]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE OrderHeader
    SET cmt_cd_1 = 'O'
    FROM OrderHeader 
    INNER JOIN inserted ON OrderHeader.ord_no = inserted.ord_no
    WHERE (OrderHeader.ord_no IN (SELECT OrderListView.ord_no
                                  FROM OrderListView))
END
```

I have verified that the header record is created first and does exist before the line item records are created. I have another trigger on this table that works fine, though the value it updates is in the same table as the trigger.

```
--TRIGGER WORKS AS DESIGNED
CREATE TRIGGER add_line_cmt
ON [OrderLine]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE OrderLine
    SET cmt_1 = 'Comment 1',
        cmt_2 = 'Comment 2'
    FROM OrderLine 
    INNER JOIN inserted ON inserted.ord_no = OrderLine.ord_no
    WHERE (OrderLine.item_no IN (SELECT CAST(item_no AS CHAR) AS item
                                 FROM ItemTable
                                 WHERE (group = 3)))
END
```

I've been banging my head against the desk for 3 hours and I know it's something simple I've missed. I'm hoping some other sets of eyes will spot it before I go nuts.

Comment: Don't materialize this. Create a view instead, that selects the headers columns plus the special columns calculated from the order's items.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? I believe it is updating but not the value you are expecting right?

Comment: dbo.POORDHDR_SQL is this the same with inserted?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @Jervs Sorry for the lack of detail. It does not update any value at all. POORDHDR is actually OrderHeader. I missed one when cleaning up the code for posting.

Comment: @marc_s I am using SQL-Server 2008R2.

Comment: @stickybit I was pretty sure that wasn't the issue but just to make sure, I did as you suggested and modified the trigger. No effect, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm afraid you might have gotten me wrong. I meant don't use any triggers at all to "physically" write the values into the table. Don't have the columns in the table. Instead create a view that calculates the values for the columns "on the fly". That way you'll always have correct values whereas materializing them might end in inconsistencies.

Comment: @stickybit oh I get what your are saying now. I did misunderstand. Unfortunately I actually have to write the value back to the table as that value triggers a function in our ERP system and I cannot make the system look elsewhere for that flag.